# How to measure the fineness of a textile fibre by diameter and fibre length?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements

I measured the diameter (um) and the fibre length (cm) of different (loose) textile fibres and have an average. Now there must be a relation between these two factors that gives an idea of the fineness.

How can I measure this (for loose fibres)?

For example for hemp fibres:

Average diameter: 86.28 um
Average length: 6.75 cm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fibre fineness is the mass per unit length. To get an accurate number you should measure this directly. But as an approximation, you can look up the density $\rho$ of the relevant fibre, and you have measured the diameter $d$, so the fineness is

$$ f=\rho \pi d^2 / 4$$

In the case of hemp, you have $d=86.28\times 10^{-4}$ cm and $\rho=1.25$ g/cm$^3$ according to [here](http://www.ipme.ru/e-journals/MPM/no_11111/suardana.pdf). So the fineness is $f=7.3\times 10^{-5}$ g/cm.